# psexec executes app on remote machine, app fails to grab MainWindowHandle / MainWindowTitle

Tags: c#, psexec

I have C# (console)application, which runs on a remote machine via psexec call - no issue.

When C# app runs on local machine, it checks different processes runs on that local machine (for local user). App looks for particular app to get handle & title but they are (wndHandle & wndTitle) blank!

```
 string wndTitle = string.Empty;
 IntPtr wndHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
 Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
 foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
 {
    if (theprocess.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("calc"))
    {
       wndHandle = theprocess.MainWindowHandle;
       wndTitle = theprocess.MainWindowTitle;
       break;
    }
 }
```

Interestingly same app is executed on the local machine.. both values are available!

Comment: Which account do you use for remote execution and is this particular account logged-in locally on the remote machine when you execute your program?

Comment: Robert, I use an account with admin privileges for remote execution where as remote machine might have different user (at different times).

Comment: Wrong session, no doubt.  Try the -i option.

Comment: Thanks **Hans**. No luck, still MainWindowHandle is ZERO!